# Output sound through speaker when not logged in

Tags: delphi, windows-7

I have a program written in Delphi XE that plays a WAV file using TMediaPlayer. The program runs in the system tray on a Windows 7 computer. The program waits for an event to trigger playing the wav file. If I am logged in on the computer itself, the wav plays fine. But if I lock the computer terminal (or log in through Remote Desktop), the wav file does not play through the computer speaker. I know the event is being triggered because all the other code in the event handler works just fine; it's just that you can't hear the wav file. I have hard-coded the volume to the maximum level so I know it's not a volume problem. Does Windows 7 have something that prevents sounds coming through the speaker if no one is currently logged in to the computer? If that limitation exists, is there a way around it?

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you just use the standard PlaySound Windows API?

Comment: Yes, the same problem occurs using PlaySound. I have also tried using Speech API and have the same problem. It's as if the sound card won't output anything unless you are logged in to the computer directly.

Comment: I know for sure that a program running can play sound with the PlaySound API function even when the console is locked.  I am not familiar with Delphi, but are you sure you have called the Win32 API directly?  If it helps, when you lock your computer, what is shown on the screen is actually a different session.  Same with Remote Desktop... it is a different session.

Comment: In my tests `PlaySound` works...

Comment: In searching around the net, sound should be working when the PC is locked... Indeed, there are even apps available that will _mute_ the sound when the PC is locked... Does the same behaviour happen on other PCs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Brad suggests, use `PlaySound()` instead of `TMediaPlayer`. It works fine when the the machine is 'locked'. Not sure about it working over a remote desktop connection though.

To confirm this, I created a new app, put a `TTimer` on the form, set the `Interval` property to 20000 and put this code in the `OnTimer` event:

```
procedure TForm13.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PlaySound('c:\windows\media\tada.wav', 0, SND_ASYNC or SND_FILENAME);
end;
```

Then I ran it, locked the console (with <kbd>Windows</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd>), and waited 20 seconds. The sound played successfully.

Comment: Working over a remote desktop connection, you need to set the connection to play the sound locally instead of on the remote machine. I know because I have had to remind colleagues to re-route their sound when they were working from home...

Comment: @Marjan, +1 on the comment, and for not resorting to wire cutters.  I'm sure it was tempting.

Comment: @Marjan: that turned out to be the problem. I was doing my install and program startup through remote desktop. Once I switched the setting in RD to keep the sound on the computer running the program, it worked beautifully.